# .htaccess file to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony application that I am using a .htaccess rule to access the /admin directory.

example.com/admin/content gives me a 404 error

example.com/backend_dev.php/admin/content gives me my symfony admin pages as expected.

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

here is the .htaccess file that currently works.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../backend.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

I have absolutely no idea how to convert this or where to start looking for tutorials.

Any help / links to tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
    rewrite ^/backend\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
 
    location /admin {
        index admin content backend.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }
 
    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /backend.php/$1 last;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony). You'll find the config for both symfony 1.x and 2.

Comment: thanks for the reply and that is what i used to get the main app working. I have a .htaccess file set up to access backend.php by using a .htaccess file in web/admin (a directory i created in symfony) accessing /admin/~ i am looking for information on .htaccess specifically.

Comment: sorry you were correct the rewrite module was in the symfony 2 section. The rewrite config in symfony 2 section worked perfectly for symfony 1.4